# why stack heap collision is not implemented in different segment

Tags: stack-overflow, heap-memory, stack-memory, heap-corruption

I think stack and heap collision could have been prevented by just putting both in different segments. Any reason it wasn't implemented that way?

Comment: what kind of system are you talking about?  which way are you comparing to?

Comment: i am talking about general programming language concept. for example in C++ compiler...

Comment: @user1096656 There are 10000 different C++ compilers for 10000 different systems. On some of those systems segmentation (or any form of protected memory) does not exist. On many systems a stack-heap-collision *will* cause a segmentation fault or a page fault. So are you asking why segmentation isn't used to protect against stack heap collision on systems that don't have protected memory? Answer: Because they don't have protected memory. Or are you asking why segmentation isn't use on systems that use guard pages instead? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Compilers produce codes that adhere to the operating system's ABI. Thus the memory model of the compiler actually follows the memory model of the operating system. If you are asking about Linux, *BSD or other OS that has flat VA with overlapping code/data/stack segments, it's easier to program that way and it greatly simplifies the memory management. Being able to prevent heap-stack collision is too small of a gain for what the OS will loose in terms of ease of memory management (managing a flat VA is already *complicated enough*).

See what happened to OS/2 - it did use full segmenting in protected mode...